# Changing active class using echo in php comand

Tags: php, class, echo

I have a problem with next code:

```
<?php 

    include("db.php");

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id_produs) FROM My_Products WHERE `id_produs_categorie`='$id_categorie' "); 
    $total_produse = mysql_result($sql, 0); 
    $total_pagini = ceil($total_produse / $produse_pe_pagina); 

    if(isset($_GET['ID'])!="")
    $id_categorie=$_GET['ID'];

    echo '<div class="row">';
        echo '<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">';
            echo '<div class="bs-example margin-top20">';
                echo '<ul class="pagination">'; 
                    echo '<li class="disabled"></li>';
                    echo '<li ( basename($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]) == "categorie.php?ID=$id_categorie&pagina=1" ? class="active" : "" )><a href="categorie.php?ID='.$id_categorie.'&pagina=1">1</a></li>';
                for ($i=2; $i<=$total_pagini; $i++) { 
                    echo '<li ( basename($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]) == "categorie.php?ID=$id_categorie&pagina=$i" ? class="active" : "" )><a href="categorie.php?ID='.$id_categorie.'&pagina='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
                }; 
                    echo '<li class="disabled"></li>';
                echo '</ul>';
            echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';

?>
```

I'm trying to change the classes based on the page user is on.

The code is good if i echo the address its ok with variables but the problem is that even if i'm on page 1 it adds also the class active to page 2 or 3.

What i'm doing wrong here?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<?php 

    include("db.php");

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id_produs) FROM My_Products WHERE `id_produs_categorie`='$id_categorie' "); 
    $total_produse = mysql_result($sql, 0); 
    $total_pagini = ceil($total_produse / $produse_pe_pagina); 

    if(isset($_GET['ID'])!="")
    $id_categorie=$_GET['ID'];
    if(isset($_GET['pagina'])!="")
    $pagina = $_GET['pagina'];

    echo '<div class="row">';
        echo '<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">';
            echo '<div class="bs-example margin-top20">';
                echo '<ul class="pagination">'; 
                    echo '<li class="disabled"></li>';
                for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pagini; $i++) { 
                    $class = $pagina == $i ? 'class="active"' : "";
                    echo '<li ' . $class .'><a href="categorie.php?ID='.$id_categorie.'&pagina='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
                }; 
                    echo '<li class="disabled"></li>';
                echo '</ul>';
            echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';

?>
```